# PyQt: nested inheritance setupUi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a custom widget getting more and more descriptive with each sub class.  For instance below, I'm adding to a list of boxes as I make them.  I want do_stuff() to only run once but I want it to run on initialization.  My problem is that I need all of the __setupUi() functions to run before I finish it.  Any help is appreciated.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class layer4:
    def __init__(self):
        self.boxes = [] 
        self.__setupUi()
        # I want to run this once AFTER all of the children (regardless of how deep it goes) have run
        self.do_stuff()


    def __setupUi(self):
        self.qsb = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.boxes.append(self.qsb)

    def do_stuff(self):
        print(self.boxes)

class layer3(layer4):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__setupUi()

    def __setupUi(self):
        self.qsb2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.boxes.append(self.qsb2)

class layer2(layer3):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__setupUi()

    def __setupUi(self):
        self.datetimebox = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
        self.boxes.append(self.datetimebox)

class layer1(layer2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__setupUi()

    def __setupUi(self):
        self.other = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
        self.boxes.append(self.other)
```

So if I run

```
t = layer2()
```

It should return 2 QSpinboxes and 1 datetimeedit

Comment: Why on earth do you think you need all those nested subclasses?

Comment: I think he thinks that segmenting the code makes his code more readable or maybe more efficient, etc, etc, and the truth is that he does the opposite. :D

Comment: How many is too many?  What if it's 3 layers instead of 4?  It's not a problem with 2 obviously but this is mostly a thought experiment.  I was thinking how could I nest ad infinitem.  I currently only have 2 but I was thinking if it would help to add a third level of description.  Apparently the consensus is "Find a better way"?

Comment: @Faller. A better way to do what, exactly? This is looking a lot like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @ekhumoro  I really am trying to subclass QtWidgets.QWidget 3 times.  Because it gets more specified with each subclass.  Currently my solution is to have the top level have a setupUi 1, 2, and 3 and overwrite them as I go down.  But that seems just clunky and bad.

Comment: @Faller. But why, though? What specific problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: Because I'm overwriting some functions to add more functionality as I get more descriptive.